# Blank Onepage Checkout with 500 Error

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

My Magento 1.9.3 store is having problems on the Checkout page when a user is logged in. No problem with guest checkouts.

https://www.caferico.co.uk/checkout/onepage/

...I get a 500 Error which is difficult to debug. I cannot find any errors listed in `/app/log/system.log` or `exception.log`. Turning on Errors is also pointless as it doesn't get that far.

Does anyone know of a fix, or how I can debug the problem?

Thanks in advance

Kevin

Comment: What webserver are you running?

Comment: You could check either `/var/log/nginx/error.log` or `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for more info

Comment: MizutiI am using cPanel on Centos. I do not have an nginx folder in my Log folder. Thanks.

Comment: I see, anything in `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log`? There must be some place where the webserver is logging its general exceptions I suppose.

Comment: Mizuti - there doesn't seem to be a usr folder.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add the following to the index.php of your website

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Dava, I have added the code and got a blank page on checkout. Looking at the source, there is no source code. I think the 500 error kicks in before magento can get a hook in it.

Comment: have you checked your logs in /var/logs/

Comment: Dava - yes. There is nothing relevant. The 500 Error kicks in before Magento gets chance to do anything...

Comment: is this still in the index.php file? also can you check unmask is set to 1

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to disable any custom module one by one to see that causes the issue?

That may be cause by a faulty module or conflicting modules.

Comment: Nhinzky. That narrowed down the error to a specific module. Thanks!

Comment: Did it fixed the issue? sorry late reply ;)